Format of ics for Google Calendar e.g Father's day
I tried to set Fathers day in Google Calendar by ics file import, the import has no error, but it doesn't appear, can somebody help me what can be the problem ?
EGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Your Organization//Your Product//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:fathers-day-20240720T120000Z@example.com
DTSTAMP:20240720T120000Z
SUMMARY:Father's Day
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=3SU;BYMONTH=6
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20240616
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20250617
STATUS:CONFIRMED
DESCRIPTION:Father's Day is celebrated on the third Sunday of June.
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR


What you provided worked for me, and the only thing I changed was EGIN to BEGIN. Have you tried refreshing the page and making sure that the calendar where you imported the event is selected in the Google Calendar?

you are right, on the 'year view' there is no any marker, but if i click on the day of Father's day it appears.

Thanks to Saddles, i made a mistake checking the event. (the event doesn't appear on the year view just by clicking on the proper day)
